# Starting existing strapi project locally

Tags: html, strapi, headless, headless-cms

How can I start existing strapi project locally?

I want to be able to run strapi dashboard locally.

I tried with npm install, npm run develop but I'm getting - npm ERR! missing script: develop.

Any help would be nice!

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So incase somebody else is still wondering how to solve this.
$ cd to your project
$  run the **npm install or yarn to install the node_modules**, and run the **npm run develop or yarn develop**.